# linux kernel option to set sata disk to udma/133 1.5gbps

Tags: linux, boot, kernel, sata, grub

i try to speed up boot time of my linux server box which uses
removable HDD rack's
the current boot time is around 2 min's but if i connect the hdd's directly to the mainboard
its about 2 sec's
the problem is that ahci's kernel implementation causes a timeout of around 30 seconds for each disk during boot which originates from the hdd-rack
after the timeout the kernel prints that the disk is limited with speed to 1.5gbps and udma/133 is used

so the question i have is:
how can i set this in grub as a boot option so the kernel doesnt have to wait for a timeout
and just hardcoded limits the speed of the disks? i read about a few options like pci=nomsi
or such, which dont work

thats why im asking for limiting precisely the disks during boot

thx

Comment: this question is fine for here, but may get better responses on Server Fault.  please don't crosspost it there; it will be migrated automatically if necessary.  if it is migrated, you need to register on Server Fault and associate your accounts to regain ownership of the post.

Comment: Is the ACHI timeout a BIOS or Linux kernel issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this

```
libata.force=1.5
```

to your boot options and it will force libata to 1.5Gbit. You can also force DMA modes etc, check out kernel-parameters.txt in your kernel documentation directory (or online say [here](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt))